# Backbone Collection jsonp ajax results not generating model correctly

Tags: backbone.js, jsonp

http://jsfiddle.net/nf8NM/3/

This is my first foray into Backbone and I am simply trying to fetch an Api call from Dribbble.

I'm trying to do it the most Backbone-native kind of way. However it seems to be doing something funny at the point it makes the collection.

I am not so bothered about actually rendering at this point, I just want the collection to setup properly with a model for each of the responses from the Api.

Any hints and direction would be great. Am I completely doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is. Rewriting a bit your collection class to separate the concerns, I get perfectly valid models.

```
Shot = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize:function(opts) {
        console.log("init shot : "+opts.id);
    }
});
ShotsList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Shot,
    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var params = _.extend({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: model.url(),
            processData: false
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        return response.shots;
    },

    url: function() {
        return "http://api.dribbble.com/players/" + encodeURIComponent(this.player) + "/shots?per_page=18";
    }
});

s=new ShotsList();
s.bind("reset",function(collection) {
    console.log(collection.models);
    console.log(collection.pluck("image_teaser_url"));
});
s.player="jordan";
s.fetch();
```

Comment: Thanks dude. I don't know what the issue was either, but after rearranging this like you had them and tidying up a few other bits it seemed to work. Thanks again.