# Backbone - Get JSON Data from API

Tags: jquery, json, twitter, backbone.js

I'm playing around with Backbone these last days..

I want to receive some data from the twitter search API. But I don't really understand how it works. This is my code:

```
(function($){

Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend();

Tweets = Backbone.Collection.extend(
    {
        model: Tweet,

        url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Hamburg&rpp=5&lang=all&callback=?',
        parse: function(response)
        {
            return response.results;
        }
    });

DefaultTweetView = Backbone.View.extend(
    {
        initialize: function(){
          _.bindAll(this, 'render');
     }

        template: _.template('<p>@<%= from_user %> <em></em></p><p><%= text %></p><p><%= location %></p>'),
        render: function()
        {

            $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });
app = new Tweet();
})(jQuery);
```

I don't think this could be right. But I don't know how to handle it :( Could someone help me or post a link where I could follow some instructions about json data and backbone please?

Answer (score 12):

### Expications

Your actual code doesn't work because you have a syntax error, and you just initialized the model.

You can't access to Twitter API without overwrite the Backbone.sync method (problem of the same origin policy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy, the solution has already posted here : [Backbone Collection jsonp ajax results not generating model correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430113/backbone-collection-jsonp-ajax-results-not-generating-model-correctly))

In my view, the best thing to learn Backbone JS is to understand how code works, and to help you, the Backbone JS documentation is here : http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

### Example

I created a working jsFiddle with your code here : http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/v4K6A/

So with it you can begin to better understand Backbone JS.