# How to get json with backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js

I am trying to use backbones.js fetch to get json from a twitter search

and my code below can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
(function($){

  var Item = Backbone.Model.extend();

  var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,
    url:"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed"
  });    

  var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    el: $('#test'),
    events: {
      'click button#add': 'getPost'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'getPost');
      this.collection = new List();
      this.render(); 
    },
    render: function(){
      var self = this;      
      $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>get</button>");
    },
    getPost: function(){
      console.log(this.collection.fetch());
    }

  });

  // **listView instance**: Instantiate main app view.
  var listView = new ListView();      
})(jQuery);​
```

I am just getting started with backbone and I just want to console.log the json

you can see my example here. jsfiddle.net/YnJ9q/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues above:

Firstly, you need to add a success/fail callback to the fetch method in order for you to have the fetched JSON logged to the console.

```
getPost: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.collection.fetch(
    {
        success: function () {
             console.log(that.collection.toJSON());
        },
        error: function() {
             console.log('Failed to fetch!');
        }
   });
}
```

Another problem is the issue of "same-origin-policy'. You can find out how to resolve that by taking a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660648/backbone-get-json-data-from-api).

**Update:**
I modified your code and included the updated `sync` method. It now works! [Take a look here!](http://jsfiddle.net/BHrmC/)

Basically, update your `collection` to include the `parse` and `sync` methods as below:

```
var List = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Item,

    url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed",

    parse: function(response) {
        return response.results;
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        var that = this;
        var params = _.extend({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: that.url,
            processData: false
        }, options);

        return $.ajax(params);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for this really struggling to get my head around backbone.js hope its worth it in the end going to stick at it. trying to get a sidebar click to return tweets at the moment

Comment: hey amulya what i dont understand is how say i wanted to have a input box to run a search on the url how you set the variable in jquery i would do "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+query+"" http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/BHrmC/1/ i dont understand how this is done with backbone???