# Backbone collection not updating with JSONP request

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, jsonp, brunch

I just recently started using Backbone.js and I'm working on an app now using Brunch that does a JSONP request to an external API to populate my collection and models. I'm following these previous posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430113/backbone-collection-jsonp-ajax-results-not-generating-model-correctly) and [this](http://iainjmitchell.com/blog/?p=777)) on doing JSONP requests with Backbone, but my collection still isn't getting the data for some reason.

My model (app/models/model.js):

```
module.exports = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

My collection (app/models/collection.js):

```
var Post = require('./model');

module.exports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Post,
    url: "http://somedata.com/api/posts/list/stuff",
    sync: function(method, model, options) {  
        options.timeout = 10000;
        options.dataType = "jsonp";
        options.jsonp = "JSONPcallback";        
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    },
    parse: function(response) {
        if (response) {
            var parsed = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
                parsed.push(response.results[i][0]);
            }

            return parsed;
        }
    }
});
```

Then, in the initialize method in app/application.js I'm calling it by:

```
var Category = require('models/collection');
this.cat = new Category();
this.cat.fetch();
```

Now, when I look at the parse function in console.log, I see the data being fetched, so the request is going through successfully. However, when my views are rendered and I do console.log(application.cat.models) in app/views/view.js, I get nothing -- why's this happening? Is there anything wrong with the code on my model/collection?

Also, the JSONP data has the following format, which is why looping through for response.results[i][0] and returning an array with all of it, that should do the trick, right?

```
{"results":[
  {"0":{"id":xxx,"title":xxx,"link":xxx},
   "description":xxx},
  {"0":{"id":xxx,"title":xxx,"link":xxx},
   "description":xxx},
  {"0":{"id":xxx,"title":xxx,"link":xxx},
   "description":xxx},...
]}
```

Would really appreciate any help...

Comment: collection.fetch() is an asyn request and needs a callback to view the data

Comment: Thanks a lot, good point - http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch says that too, and that it shouldn't be used on page loads. It says reset() is used to boostrap a collection in the initial page load. So, I should be doing an ajax request for this data in application.js and have this.cat.reset() as a success callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have 2 comments here :

1. I see that you have names both your model and collection as `module.exports` , a common practice is to make the model as singular (module.export) and make the collection for those models plural `module.exports` , just common practice , nothing "wrong" otherwise
2. You can have 2 callbacks in your code , when the collection is done fetching data(asynchronous event) also considering module.exports as your collection here ,

A. You could do this :

```
module.exports.fetch({
success : function(data){
console.log(JSON.stringiy(data));
//do remaining programming here
}
});
```

B. you could have a event listener for `reset` , from the documentation [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) , the collection fires a `reset` event when it completes the fetch , so could add an event listener on the collection like this :

```
module.exports.on('reset',function(data){
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
//do remaining programming here
},this);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've done a this.collection.bind('reset', this.collectionView.render) before calling fetch() and that did the trick.